# dialog fire multiple events at the same time

Tags: jquery, onclick

`.on("click")` produced multiple event, why? Can somebody explain me?

```
$("#office_holder_delete").on("click", function (event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  var $message = "Oops! Something went wrong while processing your request!";
  dialog($message, function () {
    alert("Yes");
  }, function () {
    alert("No");
  });
});

function dialog(message, yesCallback, noCallback) {
  $("#alert_worn").html(message);
  $(".alert").css("background-color", "#F00");
  $(".alert-content").css("display", "flex");

  $("#yes_button").on("click", function () {
    $(".alert-content").css("display", "none");
    $(".alert").css({"height": "200px"});
    $(".alert p").css("text-align", "center");
    yesCallback();
  });

  $("#no_button").on("click", function () {
    $(".alert-content").css("display", "none");
    $(".alert").css({"height": "200px"});
    $(".alert p").css("text-align", "center");
    noCallback();
  });
}
```

I expected every "click" only one "Yes" of "No", but if I click next time it produced 2 times "Yes" or "No" . If I click third time it produced three times "Yes" or "No". Why? I do not understand. I am a new in jQuery For me if I call function one time it has to produce one response. But in my reality it looks weird!

Comment: Ok The problem is each time you clicked the `office_holder_delete` it creates another `click` event for `yes/no` buttons ..  simple way to avoid this is to add `.off()` so your code will be `.off('click').on('click' , ....`

Answer (score 0):

Every time you call the `dialog` function it in turn calls `on`, setting up *another* listener on the buttons. So the next time you click, it fires twice.

Set them up globally outside the function so they are set up only once.